# How to hide safari address bar across all pages of HTML website?

Tags: html, ios, mobile, safari, hide

I'm a complete newbie to writing HTML code so I apologise in advance for any incorrect explanations/terminology I use. So basically I'm creating a really simple website in HTML which allows the user to just click between different pages of content. It's intended to be used on mobile only (i.e. on IOS saved to home screen through safari). To create more of an 'app-like' feel I'm wanting to hide the address bar/generic safari navigation buttons along the bottom. I'm able to do this on the first page (i.e. the one that I use to save to home screen), but as soon as you navigate to a different page within the website, the address bar and whatnot reappears (even though each of those pages has the same code to hide the address bar as the first). I've been using the code structure below to hide the address bar and whatnot (which works on all pages) but only on the first page viewed through the 'saved-to-homescreen' app and not subsequent pages. Any suggestion on how to get around this? Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Entrees page</title>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Entrees Page" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
</head>
<body>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do some research into `Progressive Web Apps` if you want an installable 'app-like' website, there's a lot more to it than a few meta tags though.

Comment: It may not be accomplished according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator).

Comment: @Jasmine Legend. For anyone else this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbbAPfDVqfY&ab_channel=dcode) sets you up perfectly to hide the address bar using PWAs and then you can just add your html code like normal. Awesome.